# Axiomatic approach to means

Tags: definitions, axioms

Recently I have been contemplating on a talk for high school children. One of my favorite topics in high school was the inequality of means. I had a great high school teacher who wrote some very nice articles (in Hebrew) about inequalities, so I was looking at some of them. This made me think about something I had wondered about when I was young, what does it mean a mean? Of course googling mean is not very useful. So I have two questions:

1. Do you know about any axiomatic approach to means?
2. Is it useful in anyway?

For instance, one could try and define a **mean** as a function $f:({\mathbb R}_{>0})^n \to {\mathbb R}$ which satisfies the following:

(i) $\min_i\{x_i\} \leq f(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n) \leq \max_{i}\{x_i\}$.

(ii) $f(ax_1,ax_2,\dotsc,ax_n)=af(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)$.

(iii) $f$ is strictly monotone in each variable.

(iv) If, in addition, $f$ is preserved by any permutation of the $x_i$'s, then we call it **symmetric**.

If $f$ is not symmetric, then one can define $G_f$, the **group of symmetries of $f$**, to be the symmetries that preserve $f$.

Comment: [This question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191307/are-all-well-behaved-mean-functions-on-mathbbr-equivalent) is related and has a bit of discussion of past work on axiomatics in the comments.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136385/mean-frechet-mean-standard-deviation

Comment: I'd give up on *strict* monotonicity (else, you give up on the median and the mode).

Comment: Concerning symmetry, one might require in addition $f(f(x,y),f(z,t))=f(f(x,t),f(z,y))$. I wrote this for $n=2$, but you can write it for every $n$ : start from a matrix of elements $x_{ij}$, and define for an arbitrary permution $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n$ the matrix $y_{ij}=x_{i\pi_i(j)}$. Then ask for $f(f(x_{1\cdot}),\ldots,f(x_{n\cdot}))=f(f(y_{1\cdot}),\ldots,f(y_{n\cdot}))$.

Answer (score 10):

On the projective line, an important invariant is the cross-ratio (actually the only projective invariant of four points). Each of the three usual means, arithmetic, harmonic and geometric, are all instances of the cross-ratio.
As an consequence, you can go from one mean to the other using an homography. I find it unexpected and I think this can be a way to introduce a bit of projective geometry. This also gives a geometric characterisation of the arithmetic mean amongst the other means.

Recall that four points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ form an **harmonic range** if their cross-ratio is equal to $-1$. We choose a point at infinity on the projective line, together with an origin $O$ and a unit point. Denote by $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ the coordinates of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ on the line.

Denote the cross-ratio by $(a,b,c,d) = {(c-a)(d-b)\over (c-b)(d-a)}$.

If $A$ is $O$, then $(0,b,c,d)=-1$ and $2/b = 1/c + 1/d$  (harmonic mean).

If $O$ is the middle of $AB$, then $(a,-a,c,d)=-1$ and $a^2 = cd$ (geometric mean).

If $A$ is the point at infinity, then $(\infty, b,c,d)=-1$ and $2b = c+d$ (arithmetic mean).

Comment: Does "if $A$ is in $O$" mean just "if $A$ is $O$"?

Comment: @LSpice This means "if A is located at the origin" but "if A is O" may be clearer.

Answer (score 7):

The paper [Social choice and topology a case of pure and applied mathematics](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0723-0869(04)80016-1) by Beno Eckmann investigates what is meant by a mean on a topological space. In particular, if $k$ is a natural number, then they define a $k$-mean to be a continuous function $f:X^{k}\rightarrow X$ such that $f(x,...,x)=x$ and $f(x_{1},...,x_{k})=f(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(k)})$ where $\sigma:\{1,...,k\}\rightarrow\{1,...,k\}$ is any permutation. (I should mention that I found out about this paper from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/203530/22277))

Answer (score 6):

Question 1 asks for axiomatic approaches to means. Let me quote something:

> The theory of means took shape in the first half of the twentieth century, with the 1930 papers of Kolmogorov [190, 192] and Nagumo [257] as well as
> Hardy, Littlewood and Pólya’s seminal book Inequalities [135], first published
> in 1934. (Aczél [1] describes the early history.) But new results continue to
> be proved. The 2009 book by Grabisch, Marichal, Mesiar and Pap lists some
> modern developments ([124], Chapter 4), and most of the characterization theorems in this chapter also appear to be new.

This is from the introduction to Chapter 5 of my own book [*Entropy and Diversity: The Axiomatic Approach*](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Etl/ed) (Cambridge University Press, 2021). Theorem 5.3.2 there states:

**Theorem** *Let $(M: (0, \infty)^n \to (0, \infty))_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions. The following are equivalent:*

- *$M$ is homogeneous, strictly increasing, symmetric and decomposable;*
- *$M$ is the power mean $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto \Bigl( \sum x_i^t \Bigr)^{1/t}$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.*

"Homogeneous", "strictly increasing" and "symmetric" are your conditions (ii)-(iv). "Decomposable" is the condition that
$$
M(x_{1,1}, \ldots, x_{1,k_1}, \ \ldots,\ x_{n,1}, \ldots, x_{n, k_n})
=
M(a_1, \ldots, a_1, \ \ldots,\ a_n, \ldots, a_n),
$$
where $a_i = M(x_{i, 1}, \ldots, x_{i, k_i})$ and there are $k_i$ copies of $a_i$ on the right-hand side. Decomposability is very powerful, and in its absence, I suspect there are many other "means".

Answer (score 2):

The following paper gives an axiomatization of the geometric mean, and suggests extensions to symmetric matrices:

*Ando, T.; Li, Chi-Kwong; Mathias, Roy*, [**Geometric means**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2003.11.019), Linear Algebra Appl. 385, 305-334 (2004). [ZBL1063.47013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1063.47013).